# How much time would pass before overwriting data on iPod/iPhone flash memory results in failure?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, apple-hardware-test

Just for the sake of this question.

Let's say I have a file that fills my iPod completely, and I set an automated test to save this file into my iPod and overwrite it, non stop. How much time will pass until the flash drive cannot write the file anymore?

I tried to Google this, but "Stress test" only means smashing your device to pieces.

Comment: Try googling "Flash memory life" for some general insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash controllers generally degrade gracefully, so once a block has failed, it no longer is usable, so you would expect a slow, gradual shrinking of the usable space over time. Once the majority of the blocks start reaching the limit on write cycles (you need to store different data - not just the same bits to make real change on most flash controllers) then this reduction of space increases more linearly with time / write cycles.

So - it will be quick to not store the entire file, but a much longer time until you can't write to 50% of the drive.